# Golang revel framework hot-reload in docker environment

Tags: go, docker, osx-yosemite, revel, fig

I'm trying to set up golang environment as described [in this great post](http://www.medding.me/blog/2014/09/06/setting-up-a-docker-environment-for-golang-development-part-1/). I'm using Docker on OS X 10.10 with boot2docker (v1.3.0) and fig.sh (1.0.1).
Everything runs fine, but revel's hot-reload not working at all. Anyone experienced same problem or know any workaround to make hot-reload work?
Revel framework version 0.11.1

Comment: What error are you seeing? There's no reason Revel shouldn't run as designed in Docker since Docker provides a shell and filesystem. I'd like to learn more about the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Boot2docker uses VirtualBox, and I'm assuming vboxsf for shared folders. [vboxsf doesn't notify about changed files](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660). Try keeping the files completely inside the virtual machine. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this for a Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.17.2-alpine AS build

# Add required packages
RUN apk add --update git curl bash

# Install revel framework
RUN go get -u github.com/revel/revel
RUN go get -u github.com/revel/cmd/revel

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

ENV CGO_ENABLED 0

ADD . .

ENTRYPOINT revel run
```

Then run using something like docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  go-revel-crud:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - ENV=dev
      - PORT=8090
```

Mounting the volume for current directory to the working dir `/app`.

Checkout this [guide](https://citizix.com/how-to-run-a-golang-revel-app-with-docker-and-docker-compose/) with full explaination